# CSS List Styling Not Lining Up

Tags: css

Trying to get these list headings to line up correctly, but I can't figure out the justification to get it to line up.  Trying to style it like the second one but those bold tags are pushing it down a line.

[image]
[image]

```
    <div class="block">
    <ul class="toc partThree">
        <li><b>39:</b><a href="#">Maintaining This Diet</a></li>
        <br/>
        <li><b class="parts">Part 3A:</b><a class="partslink" href="#"> About Fruit Consumption</a></li>
        <li><b>40:</b><a href="#">Ideal Fruit-combinations</a></li>
        <li><b>41:</b><a href="#">Fruits To Go</a></li>
        <li><b>42:</b><a href="#">Salads &amp; Shakes</a></li>
        <li><b>43:</b><a href="#">Fruits In General</a></li>
        <li><b>44:</b><a href="#">About Consuming Nuts</a></li>
        <br/>
        <li><b class="parts">Part 3B:</b><a class="partslink" href="#"> About Consuming Animal Food</a></li>
        <li><b>45:</b><a href="#">About Fresh Raw Fish</a></li>
        <li><b>46:</b><a href="#">About Fresh Raw Egg Yolk</a></li>
        <br/>
        <li><b class="parts">Part 3C:</b><a class="partslink" href="#"> The Most Important Section of This book</a></li>
        <li><b>47:</b><a href="#">Remember That...</a></li>
        <li><b>48:</b><a href="#">The Rules</a></li>
        <li><b>49:</b><a href="#">The Obstacles</a></li>
        <li><b>50:</b><a href="#">Cravings</a></li>
        <li><b>51:</b><a href="#">Traps</a></li>
        <li><b>52:</b><a href="#">How To Pick Munch-foods</a></li>                          
        <li><b>53:</b><a href="#">Protein Contents</a></li>
        <li><b>54:</b><a href="#">Single Munch-food Items</a></li>                          
        <li><b>55:</b><a href="#">Munch-food Meals</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .toc{
    list-style:none;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.toc li{
        margin:0 0 0 10px;
        width: 220px;
        overflow:hidden;
        font-size:13px;
        font-family:Arial;
    }
    .toc b{
        float:left;
        padding: 0 4px 0 0;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .toc a{
        float:left;
        width:191px;
        padding:0 0 0 0px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .toc a:hover{
        color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    b.parts{

    }
    a.partslink{

    }
```

Comment: Do you know about the existence of [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/counter-reset) CSS property...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QbUvD/

Made some adjustments, particularly removing floats. This is assuming you don't use the suggestion above of the counter-reset (although with that you'd have to restructure a lot of your HTML it seems).

the trick I used here is to add a padding-left to the li's that are title (add a class .title) then using a negative text-indent to wrap back the first line, but allow the second one to keep the padding. The only downside here is the need for a manual width on the padding/indent values, but it achieves the look you want.

Comment: That helps but I would like it to still be indented with the text above it, not wrapping beneath the bold header.  But that looks better for sure.